# Find the closest number via a look up?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to find the closest number from a table.

Example - I have the below set of figures

```
Column 1    Column 2
 € 1,187,385     € 19,547.82 
 € 949,430   € 30,404.75 
 € 935,216   € 19,704.01 
 € 907,508   € 28,912.47 
 € 865,841   € 21,698.54 
 € 844,429   € 26,468.55 
 € 741,769   € 26,687.78 
 € 729,647   € 28,750.40 
 € 711,840   € 11,909.60 
 € 690,197   € 22,172.20 
 € 659,998   € 15,919.33 
 € 657,956   € 9,134.46 
 € 648,282   € 13,700 
 € 634,949   € 7,802 
 € 631,214   € 6,407
```

I have a look up value of 730,000 - as this is not an 100% match - is there a way that it would find the closest match to that number (730,00) - realise it is 729,647 & then tell excel to show the figure in column 2 (28,780.40)

A few more examples:

If I search for the figures in Column A - the results would be as followed.

```
 € 730,000   € 26,687.78 
 € 1,239,636     € 19,547.82 
 € 693,365   € 22,172.20 
 € 631,283   € 6,407
```

Vlookup with true match

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastRowA As Long, LastRowD As Long
    Dim Value As Long
    Dim Differ As Long
    Dim Result As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowD = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Differ = 0

        For i = 2 To LastRowD

            Value = .Range("D" & i).Value

            For j = 2 To LastRowA

                If j = 2 Then
                    Differ = Abs(Value - .Range("A" & j).Value)
                    Result = .Range("B" & j).Value
                Else
                    If Abs(Value - .Range("A" & j).Value) < Differ Then
                        Differ = Abs(Value - .Range("A" & j).Value)
                        Result = .Range("B" & j).Value
                    End If
                End If

            Next j

            .Range("E" & i).Value = Result

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This formula should work:

```
=IF(LOOKUPVAL>MAX(COLUMN1),FIRSTVAL,INDEX(COLUMN2,IF(ABS(LOOKUPVAL-INDEX(COLUMN1,MATCH(LOOKUPVAL,COLUMN1,-1)))<ABS(LOOKUPVAL-INDEX(COLUMN1,MATCH(LOOKUPVAL,COLUMN1,-1)+1)),MATCH(LOOKUPVAL,COLUMN1,-1),MATCH(LOOKUPVAL,COLUMN1,-1)+1)))
```

where `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2` are the ranges that corresponds to your look-up table (with the €'s and spaces edited out to give plain numbers), `FIRSTVAL` is the first value in column 2, and `LOOKUPVAL` is the range of the value you want to look up.

**HOW IT WORKS**

**A**. You can find the index of the smallest value in column 1 that is greater than `LOOKUPVAL` with:

```
=MATCH(LOOKUPVAL,COLUMN1,-1)
```

Since your values are sorted in descending order we use `-1` the third parameter. For convenience we'll call this **INDEX1**.

**B**. Since your values are in descending order, the next value in column 1 will be smaller than `LOOKUPVAL`. We can get it's index with:

```
=INDEX1+1
```

We'll call this **INDEX2**.

**C**. We can look up the values associated with these two indices:

```
=INDEX(COLUMN1,INDEX1)
=INDEX(COLUMN1,INDEX2)
```

We'll call these **VALUE1** and **VALUE2**, respectively.

**D**. We get the distances of `LOOKUPVAL` from each of **VALUE1** and **VALUE2** by

```
=ABS(LOOKUPVAL-VALUE1)
=ABS(LOOKUPVAL-VALUE2)
```

We'll call these **DISTANCE1** and **DISTANCE2**, respectively.

**E**. We get the desired index depending on which of **DISTANCE1** and **DISTANCE2** is smaller:

```
=IF(DISTANCE1<DISTANCE2,INDEX1,INDEX2)
```

We'll call this **DESIREDINDEX**.

**F**. Finally we lookup the desired column 2 value:

```
=INDEX(COLUMN2,DESIREDINDEX)
```

**G**. To get the long, cumbersome formula at the top of this answer, you start at the bottom and *back-substitute*.

**H**. As a final step we need to protect the `MATCH` function from errors when it tries to look up a number that is larger than anything in column 1. To do that we wrap the whole thing in an `IF`:

```
=IF(LOOKUPVAL>MAX(COLUMN1),FIRSTVAL,Proceed as described above)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be this **ARRAY-FORMULA  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1+MIN(ABS(C1-$A$1:$A$15)),$A$1:$B$15,2,0),VLOOKUP(C1-MIN(ABS(C1-$A$1:$A$15)),$A$1:$B$15,2,0))
```

This just looks for the lowest absolute difference between the `lookupvalue` and your data.

[image]